# Rounded number to a best suitable nearest number so that i can calculate the interval thats are factor of 2, 5 or 10

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

There can be any specified number, then I want to write a function to return the best upper limit number to calculate the interval.

To divide the number into 5 intervals, the best numbers are

1. if less than or equal **5** = divide into 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2. if **10** => divide into 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
3. if **25** => divide into 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
4. if **50** => divide into 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
5. if **100** => divide into 20, 40, 60, 80, 100
6. if **125** => divide into 25, 50, 75, 100, 125
7. If **500** => divide into 100, 200, 300, 400, 500

But the input number, cannot be that 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 125, 500, ...

So I would like to write a function that can return the best bold number, but i am stuck now. I want to calculate on the fly. No predefined values as I don't know what would be the input number.
For less than or equal to 10, i can add additional to handle, but greater than 10, I want to get through by some formula calculation.

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 10 |
| 13 | 25 |
| 110 | 125 |
| 456 | 500 |
| 1601 | 2000 |
| 53194 | 60000 |

Is there any formula to calculate so that I can write the function that takes the above input and return the output? Thanks a lot.

The reason not to split 110 into 22, 44, 66, 88, 110,  these numbers are not suitable to appear in the chart axis except 2, 4, 6, 8 , 10.

Comment: `if 100 => divide into 20, 40, 50, 80, 100` 50 should be 60 here. And `if 125 => divide into 25, 50, 100, 125, 150` <- what's the logic here?

Comment: I really don't get your system of intervals. While the intervals for 10, 25 and 50 are of the same size, the invervals for 100 suddenly have different sizes. And for 125 the last value is even greater than the number itself? And why can't we spit 110 into "22, 44, 66, 88, 110"?

Comment: @adiga That should probably be `25, 50, 75, 100, 125`

Comment: @adiga I'm pretty sure those are just typos.

Comment: Is your question just about finding the next greater of the bold numbers? Or on how to calculate such a "best number" in general. Ie what happens if the input is 53194? What would the "best number" be in that case?

Comment: @derpirscher, these interval numbers are for the chart axis, so 22, 44 are not good to show. For 53194, I want 60000.

Comment: @adiga Thanks a lot for pointing out the typo error.

Comment: How about if the input is 5? Should it be 1,2,3,4,5 or round up to 2,4,6,8,10?

Comment: Again the question: Do you want a general formula which calculates intervals for any input on the fly or do you have a set of predefined intervals and you just want to find the best fitting from that set?

Comment: @derpirscher I want general formula to calculate on the fly. I cannot control the input value. It is dynamic depending on the backend server data.

Comment: @Stuart, for input 5, that will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: So steps of 12000 are fine but not steps of 12 or 120? A clear definition is needed of what constitute a nice looking interval for any input number.

Comment: @Stuart your question of 12000 interval is good but not 12 or 120.  I am very struggling getting this upper limit value, as i want this upper value in y-axis highest, not too far away from the largest input value of 53194, so i choose to be 60000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest defining your interval in some way like this:

[image: For a positive input number n, find the minimum interval i such that 5i >= n and i is one of the following forms: 10^k, 2(10^k), 5(10^k), or 25(10^k), where k is a non-negative integer]

You can then solve the resulting inequalities by taking logarithms, and take the minimum viable solution to find the interval.

```js
function interval(n, steps=5) {

  // Find the minimum x such that x = a*b^k >= n / steps, where k is an integer 
  const solve = (a, b) => a * b ** Math.ceil(Math.log((n / steps) / a) / Math.log(b));

  // Return the lowest of the possible solutions    
  return Math.min(
    solve(1, 10),
    solve(2, 10),
    solve(5, 10),
    solve(25, 10)
  ); 
}
// alternatively const interval = (n, steps=5) => Math.min(...[1, 2, 5, 25].map(a => a * 10 ** Math.ceil(Math.log10((n / steps) / a))));
const inputs = [5, 8, 13, 110, 456, 1601, 53194];
console.log("input\t int\t limit");
for (const n of inputs) {
  console.log(n, '\t', interval(n), '\t', 5 * interval(n));
}
```

This does not match your suggested output in all cases, but does provide sensible and consistent values. You could adjust the forms that are allowed if you want to tweak this.